# How to charge a customer and direct funds to another account

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently only seeing a way to charge customers to yourself based on https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object
. Is there any way to set the destination to another stripe account? Basically, charge a customer whos funds then go directly to another account? The platform is acting as a facilitator and is not intended to take control of the funds during this process, but instead simply move them from one custoemr to another.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Stripe Connect is for: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/